# Cannot generate different colours using qplot for geom=density

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I am trying to generate a density plot using `qplot` for a `factor` variable. I used the following code

```
qplot(
    file1$month, 
    geom = "density", 
    main ="Density function of Months", 
    xlab = "Month", 
    col=I(("red")))
```

which works for coloring all the lines but i need different colors for each line **i.e. 12 for 12 months**. Error says **aesthetics must be equal to data which is 4613**. I clearly don't have data of 4613. How to plot different colors for each month?

Comment: Please share a subset of your data?  Without knowing what your data is like, I can only hazard a guess.  Try calling `col` on a factorized variable with levels equal to the 12 month names

Comment: Probably something like `ggplot(file1, aes(x=value_var, colour=color_var)) + geom_density()`, where `value_var` is the column with the data, and `color_var` is the column with the month categories.

Comment: colour=colour_var worked just fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a column in `file1` which identifies which rows are which colours. Say you generate that column and it's called `plotColor'. Then it's as simple as

```
qplot(
    file1$month, 
    geom = "density", 
    main ="Density function of Months", 
    xlab = "Month", 
    colour= file1$plotColour)
```

Without seeing your data it's hard to give any more advice than that. But I believe you just need a different column which helps distinguish which colours each need to be, and that's what the above solution will give you.

Comment: I don't need x and y just x which is a density plot of months. I got it just as you have specified by setting colour to the variable months.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, my apologies. I forgot about the 'density' part!

Comment: Just curious. If i didn't like the default colors, how to set my own colors? I know to create color_var to store values of colors, but since the previous error showed me 4613 data, i can't store that many colors where i just need 12.

Comment: To set colors manually, add the following to the plot code: `+ scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "blue"))`, where `values` is a vector of colors containing at least as many colors as there are categories in the relevant data column. To create a large number of colors, you can do something like `scale_color_manual(values=hcl(seq(15,375,length.out=13)[1:12], 100, 65))`, which will create a sequence of 12 evenly space hues. You can also use built-in color palettes, like `scale_color_brewer` or, from the `viridis` package, `scale_color_viridis`.